# How to correctly download images and use it?

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, ionic-framework

The travel application I'm working on should support offline mode. To get it working I'm downloading all city images upon user request to corodova.file.documentsDirectory/images. Download is working fine. However, when I try to set img src to corodova.file.documentsDirectory/images/myimage nothing happens and I'm seeing the following error in the console: "Not allowed to load local resource".

I tried different approach and downloaded the images to corodova.file.applicationDirectory/www/img/ and than I set the img src simply to img/my-city/whatever. This is working ok on simulator but when testing on iphone it fails to create the my-city directory with error code 3.

I'm working on ios environment.

Any idea?